# Is this the correct usage of an angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am very very new to angular, and am trying to make a directive that allows users that are admins to modify the content on a web page, and if the user is not an admin, just displays the content in a noneditable format.  I decided to call this directive "blurb", and I have defined it as follows:

blurb-modules.js:

```
    ;(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('blurb', ['ngSanitize', 'mdotTamcCouncil.core']);

})();
```

blurb-directive.js

```
; (function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('blurb')
        .directive('mcgiBlurb', blurb);

    function blurb() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: jsGlobals.componentsFolder + '/blurb/blurb.html',
            controller: function ($scope, blurbsFactory, userFactory) {
                $scope.content = "";
                $scope.blurbs = {};
                $scope.currentUser = {};
                this.editMode = false;


                userFactory().success(function (data) {
                    $scope.currentUser = data;
                });

                blurbsFactory().success(function (data) {
                    $scope.blurbs = data;
                    $scope.content = $scope.blurbs[$scope.textKey];
                });

                this.enterEditMode = function () {
                    this.editMode = true;
                };

                this.saveEdits = function () {
                    this.editMode = false;
                    $scope.blurbs[$scope.textKey] = $scope.content;
                };
            },
            controllerAs: 'blurb',
            scope: {
                textKey: "@"
            }
        };
    };
})();
```

blurb.html

```
<div>
    <form name="blurbForm" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group" 
             ng-show="currentUser.isAdmin && blurb.editMode" 
             ng-class="{ 'has-error' : blurbForm.content.$invalid && !blurbForm.content.$pristine, 'has-success' : !blurbForm.content.$invalid && !blurbForm.content.$pristine }">
            <textarea name="content" class="form-control" rows="6" ng-model="content" required="true"></textarea>
            <p ng-show="blurbForm.content.$invalid && !blurbForm.content.$pristine">Content is required.</p>
            <div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-disabled="blurbForm.$invalid" ng-click="blurb.saveEdits()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign icon-white"></i> Save Changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-hide="blurb.editMode">
            <p ng-bind-html="content"></p>
            <div ng-show="currentUser.isAdmin">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="blurb.enterEditMode()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil icon-white"></i> Edit</button></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I then instantiate it on my index.html as follows:

```
<mcgi-blurb text-key="mainPageTest"></mcgi-blurb>
```

I created the following services to be used by the directive, with the hope that I would eventually be able to extract them out into data retrieved from a WebAPI.

blurb-service.js

```
(function () {
    angular.module('mdotTamcCouncil.core').factory('blurbsFactory', function ($http) {
        var promise = null;

        return function () {
            if (promise) {
                // If we've already asked for this data once,
                // return the promise that already exists.
                return promise;
            } else {
                promise = $http.get(jsGlobals.blurbsDataURL);
                return promise;
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

user-service.js

```
(function () {
    angular.module('mdotTamcCouncil.core').factory('userFactory', function ($http) {
        var promise = null;

        return function () {
            if (promise) {
                // If we've already asked for this data once,
                // return the promise that already exists.
                return promise;
            } else {
                promise = $http.get(jsGlobals.userDataURL);
                return promise;
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

And this all works.  Which seems great.  But I have this sneaky suspicion that I am not using directives in the way they are meant.  I have a bunch of "logic" that controls how the html is displayed in the html template, and that seems a little "dirty"/"hacky"/"I don't know".

Is this the correct way to implement an angular directive?  Should I have parts of this in a different location?  If so, where?

Comment: It does seem like a contrived example. If your logic is simply "If the user is an administrator, allow them to edit the text" then the text could go in a styled <input> control then you could just use the ngReadonly directive https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly

Comment: If you use @jonnyknowsbest method, you'll need to make sure you check on the server side if they are an admin or user since you can remove the read only attribute in the web inspector and still submit

Answer (score 0):

To make fields uneditable you can simply use **ng-readonly** directive like here: `<INPUT ng-readonly="expression">...</INPUT>` 
and use **ng-if** in place of **ng-show** to make content visible user-role base, as ng-if dosn't let DOM render if expression returns false.

ng-readonly [ng-readonly documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly)

ng-if [ng-if directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)